# Delete all occurence of href tag and keep the textes inside

Tags: javascript

I have a long String containing a HTML document. I want to delete all the href Tags but keep the text. The following example:

```
Some text <a href="mailto:mail@example.com">example 1</a></p> some <a href="www.example2.com"> example 2</a>text
```

should become:

```
Some text example 1 </p> some example 2 text
```

The solution I found is to get all the textes, and then try to iterate again through the text and replace the  tag number n with the text number n.

```
var a_string = 'Some text <a href="mailto:mail@example.com">example 1</a></p> some <a href="www.example2.com"> example 2</a>text',
el = document.createElement('p');
el.innerHTML = a_string;
var a = el.querySelectorAll('a');
var texts = [].slice.call(a).map(function(val){
   return val.innerHTML;
});
alert(texts);
// TODO ieterate and replace occurence n with texts[n]
```

Is there a besser way to do this?

Comment: Are there ever any tags nested inside the `<a>`s? Eg `<a href...><img src...>`?

Comment: No there is no nested Tags

Comment: "Is there a besser way to do this?" — Questions about improving working code belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (make sure you take their tour and learn how to write questions in the right format for that site).

Comment: Why is this needed? Is it not just going to be put right back on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After first line write following code

```
a_string = a_string.replace(/(<a.*?>)/g,'').replace(/<\/a>/g,' ');
```

Comment: This regular expression does not fulfill the OP requirements as it excludes the <a> tag content.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it gives: "Some text </p> some text"

Comment: @Zim you have right, I did not notice it - I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Regex:

```
var regex = /(<\s*a([^>]+)>|<\/\s*a\s*>)/ig;
var str = 'Some text <a href="mailto:mail@example.com">example 1</a></p> some <a href="www.example2.com"> example 2</a>text';

str.replace(regex, "");  //Some text example 1</p> some  example 2text
```

Comment: I get Some text undefinedexample 1undefined</p> some  undefinedexampleundefined 2text as result

Comment: Try with `.replace(regex, " ");` (space character instead of no character)

Comment: If you get such output, it can only be because you used an undefined 2nd argument for `replace`. This error is not due to the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex:

```
var a_txt = a_string.replace(/<a[\s]+[^>]*?href[\s]?=[\s\"\']*(.*?)[\"\']*.*?>/g,"").replace(/<\/a>/g," ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution of query-selecting all a-tags isn't actually too bad. Instead of getting the text with map you could just iterate over the list and replace each element with its content. No need for regular expressions:

```
el.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function( a_el ){
    var text = document.createTextNode(a_el.innerText);
    a_el.parentNode.replaceChild(text, a_el);
});
```

also, instead of "parsing" your html by putting it into a p-element, you could use a DomParser:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(a_string, "text/html");

doc.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function( a_el ){
    var text = document.createTextNode(a_el.innerText);
    a_el.parentNode.replaceChild(text, a_el);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as stated in some answer above, your code isn't bad. I avoid the use of regular expression when not necessary.
To finish your code, you neeed to iterate through all A{ELEMENTS}. I am typing from mobile phone. Let me know if you hit an error. Thanks.

```
var a_string = 'Some text <a href="mailto:mail@example.com">example 1</a></p> some <a href="www.example2.com"> example 2</a>text',

el = document.createElement('p');
el.innerHTML = a_string;
var a = el.querySelectorAll('a');

for( var t = a.length - 1; t >=0 ; t-- ){
   for(var c = a[t].childNodes.length - 1; c >= 0; c-- ){
       if( a[t].nextSibling ){
           document.insertBefore( a[t].childNodes[c], a[t].nextSibling  );
        } else {
     a[t].parentNode.appendChild( a[t].childNodes[c]);
        }
   }
   a[t].remove();
}
```